# How do I fire the same event on multiple links when hover over - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a simple function using an eventhandler and could use some help or pointers as to where I can work out how to do it.

I have 3 link elements with titles inside them. When the mouse enters the element I want the titles to slide out of view (garage door effect) and the opposite when the mouse leaves the element.

I have managed to write the first part. I can get the element to hide the titles on hover but don't know how to have the event fire separately on different elements rather than at once.

Or how to get the event to fire on mouse leave.

Should I use the .hover() event or .mouseenter() and .mouseleave()

Here's my code so far http://jsbin.com/miwen/6/

Comment: Post relevant code in question, read SO rules.

Comment: The ID must be unique. Use $('a') instead of $('#go')

Comment: You can't have multiple `ID`s that are the same. Also you'll probably need to use `$(this)` to refer to that element..

Answer (score 1):

The `.hover()` method binds handlers for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave events`. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.

Also id must be unique. So replace `#go` with `a`.

In the end you shoulb put `stop()` that you stop animation currently running and hasnot finished

Try

```
 $( "a" ).hover(
  function() {
     $(this).find(".title").stop().animate({
top: "600px"
}, 1500 );
  }, function() {
     $(this).find(".title").stop().animate({
top: "200px"
}, 1500 );
  }
);
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sukajoho/3/edit)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to understand thanks. Is there a specific term for this kind of function so that I can read up on it. I wasn't sure what to look for on Jquery.com. Is this called traversing?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$( "a" ).hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find(".title").animate({
            top: "600px"
        }, 1500 );    
    }, function() {
        $(this).find(".title").animate({
            top: "200px"
        }, 1500 );  
    }
);
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xYC2P/2/)